# Wordpress paths doesn't contain slashes

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, xampp

I have a wordpress instance on local machine with XAMPP.

I'm unable to pass proper wordpress paths to my plugin because the wordpress constants doesn't contain slashes in path.
Here is example of my plugin paths and the real path that is generated:

Plugin path:

```
define('__WPPM_ADMIN_CSS__', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'admin' . '/css');
```

Generated path:

```
https://localhost/wwwebowniaC:xampphtdocswwwebowniawp-contentpluginswp-portfolio-manager/admin/css/admin.css?ver=5.8.2
```

Here is content of .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Dyrektywy zawarte między "BEGIN WordPress" oraz "END WordPress"
# są generowane dynamicznie i powinny być modyfikowane tylko za pomocą
# filtrów WordPressa. Zmiany dokonane bezpośrednio tutaj będą nadpisywane.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong or what's wrong with my xampp localhost?

Comment: The problem is that you tried to use a file system path, in a place that actually expects a URL. You need to use `plugin_dir_url`.

Comment: @CBroe You're so genius. It works like a charm. Thank you for help. :)

Comment: Please add your solution as an "answer" (and accept it).

Answer (score 1):

I mistook function names. I should use plugin_dir_url instead of plugin_dir_path.